# Cannot get the first value of stream, BLOC pattern in flutter

Tags: flutter, stream, reactive-programming, rxdart

I am making my first project using BLOC pattern and I am stuck on this one thing. I have made a bloc class and put a search function inside. I want to search through the very first value of the stream and add the result to the stream. but for some reason the complier does not go into that logic.
Kindly tell me what's wrong. is there a better way to do this. I have not been able to find any extensive demo or documentation on reactive programming.

```
import 'package:mathecad/Models/assignment.dart';
import 'package:mathecad/Resources/repository.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AssignmentBloc {
  final _repository = Repository(true);
  final _assignmentStream = PublishSubject<List<Assignment>>();

  Stream<List<Assignment>> get assignments => _assignmentStream.stream.asBroadcastStream();

  getAssignments() async {
    List<Assignment> list = await _repository.getAllAssignments();
    _assignmentStream.sink.add(list);
  }

  filterByCourse(String course) async {
    List<Assignment> _filteredAssignments = [];
    if (course == 'All') {
      _assignmentStream.first.then((assignmentList) => _assignmentStream.sink.add(assignmentList));
    } else {
      assignments.first.then((asssignmentList) {  
        asssignmentList.forEach((assignment) {   //  =========== code not executed =============
          if (assignment.session.course.name == course) {
            _filteredAssignments.add(assignment);
          }
        });
        _assignmentStream.sink.add(_filteredAssignments);
      }, onError: (error) {
        print("Error" + error);
      });
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _assignmentStream.close();
  }
}
```

The stream is used to build a list view in a screen.

```
Expanded(
              flex: 15,
              child: StreamBuilder(
                initialData: null,
                stream: _bloc.assignments,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Assignment>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return AssignmentTile(assignment: snapshot.data[index]);
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      strokeWidth: 3,
                    ));
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `filterByCourse` method of `AssignmentBloc`?

Comment: I am calling that function from my "assignment screen" on a button tap basically.